# I moved id_rsa and now no programs can find it

Tags: nautilus, ssh, mysql, 15.04

I am planning on doing a clean installation of Ubuntu.

I am concerned that, when I do a clean installation, my private keys will be lost and I will be locked out of my servers for which I disabled passwords.

In order to test this, I simulated what I would do during a clean install - I copied `~/.ssh/id_rsa` into a backup medium and then I copied `id_rsa` back into the `~/.ssh` folder, as though nothing had happened.

According to `ls -al`, the file still exists:

```
noob  ~/.ssh λ ls -al
total 24
drwx------  2 noob noob 4096 Jun  5 08:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 43 noob noob 4096 Jun  6 10:36 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 noob noob  748 May 31 15:44 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 noob noob 3326 May 31 15:44 is_rsa
-rw-------  1 noob noob 3620 Jun  1 11:48 known_hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 noob noob 2827 Jun  1 08:50 known_hosts.old
```

And when I double click the `id_rsa` file in Nautilus, I am prompted for my password to unlock the key. When I enter the correct password, I can see the strength, fingerprints, etc. *Seems* good...

Howver, when I run:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I am told "File not found"

( I am certain the path is correct as I usually `cd` first instead of using the full path)

And when I connect to my server using SSH, I am prompted for my password. Similarly, when I connect to MySQL via Workbench SSH, I am told the file cannot be found.

What has happened here? How can I make the key visible to other programs again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have for some reason named the file "is_rsa" instead of "id_rsa".

Also you should have copied the id_rsa.pub file, but you may be able to recover it from another host you have set up for password-free login.

Last time I did this I archived the .ssh folder instead.

Comment: I realized what I did as soon as I posted the answer! I cannot answer my own question at this time, though. Thank you, Thorbjørn.

Comment: I have no idea how that happened. I think I may have used `mv` and done a typo.

Comment: This is what drills are for!  You are very careful and that will benefit you later.